# np.copy(obj) vs obj.copy() vs copy.copy(obj) vs copy.deepcopy(obj)

Tags: python-3.x

**np.copy(obj) vs obj.copy() vs copy.copy(obj) vs copy.deepcopy(obj)**

I see that there are basically four methods we can use for copying object in Python.
I am not crystal clear about the differences between the four.

Someone please explain the differences from the ground.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR they differ in copy method:

- Shallow copy:

  - `numpy.copy()`
  - `(dict | list | ...).copy()`
  - `copy.copy()`
- Deep copy:

  - `copy.deepcopy()`

Also by the purpose:

- Copy data structure:

  - `numpy.copy()`
  - `(dict | list | ...).copy()`
- Copy object (data structure ⊂ object):

  - `copy.copy()`
  - `copy.deepcopy()`

Plus, `copy.copy()` or `copy.deepcopy()` will internally call `obj.__copy__()` and `obj.__deepcopy__()` methods respectively, if exists - Which means user classes can control the copying behavior.

---

### Explanation about Shallow copy & Deep copy

There's 2 kind of copy in python: *Shallow copy* and *Deep copy*.

From [Python documents](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/copy.html?highlight=copy#copy.copy):

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for **compound objects** (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):
>
> - A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) **inserts references** into it to the objects found in the original.
> - A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, **recursively, inserts copies** into it of the objects found in the original.

Such difference is best shown when we copy class instance.

```py
>>> class SomeClass:
...     pass

>>> a = [SomeClass()]
>>> b = a.copy()

>>> a[0] == b[0]
True

>>> id(a[0])
2778700770576
>>> id(b[0])
2778700770576

# Not actually copied, referencing to same instance.
```

```py
>>> import copy
>>> a = [SomeClass()]
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)

>>> a[0] == b[0]
False

>>> id(a[0])
2778695702544
>>> id(b[0])
2778717746032

# Actually copied into different instance
```

For shallow copy, if your data contain compound object - most commonly `list`, `dict`, user classes, etc - and you have to work on it, make sure to use *Deep copy* to avoid things like below:

```py
>>> a = [[0], [0]]
>>> b = a.copy()

>>> b[0].append(10)

>>> a
[[0, 10], [0]]
>>> b
[[0, 10], [0]]

# ---

>>> a = [[0], [0]]
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)

>>> b[0].append(10)

>>> a
[[0], [0]]
>>> b
[[0, 10], [0]]
```